# How to explicitly acknowledge/fail Amazon SQS FIFO queue from the listener without throwing an exception?

Tags: amazon-sqs

My application only listens to a certain queue, the producer is the 3rd party application. I receive the messages but sometimes based on some logic I need to send fail message to the producer so that the message is resend to my listener again until I decide to consume it and acknowledge it. My current implementation of this process is just throwing some custom exception. But this is not a clean solution, therefore can any one help me to send FAIL to producer without throwing exception.

My JMS Listener Factory settings:

```
@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactoryForQexpress(SQSErrorHandler errorHandler) {
    SQSConnectionFactory connectionFactory = SQSConnectionFactory.builder()
        .withRegion(RegionUtils.getRegion(StaticSystemConstants.getQexpressSqsRegion()))
        .withAWSCredentialsProvider(new ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider(StaticSystemConstants.getQexpressSqsCredentials()))
        .build();
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    factory.setDestinationResolver(new DynamicDestinationResolver());
    factory.setConcurrency("3-10");
    factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    factory.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
    return factory;
}
```

My Listener Settings:

```
    @JmsListener(destination = StaticSystemConstants.QUEXPRESS_ORDER_STATUS_QUEUE, containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactoryForQexpress")
public void receiveQExpressOrderStatusQueue(String text) throws JSONException {
    LOG.debug("Consumed QExpress status {}", text);
    //here i need to decide either acknowlege or fail
    ...
    if (success) {
         updateStatus();
    } else {
         //todo I need to replace this with explicit FAIL message
         throw new CustomException("Not right time to update status");
    }

}
```

Please, share your experience on this. Thank you!

Comment: It's not clear what you want, here... SQS provides no mechanism for backwards messages to the producer.

Comment: That's what I wanted to clarify. Whether it is possible to explicitly acknowledge or fail the received message. You are saying it is impossible?

Answer (score 1):

SQS -- internally speaking -- is fully asynchronous and  completely decouples the producer from the consumer.

Once the producer successfully hands off a message to SQS and receives the message-id in response, the producer only knows that SQS has received and committed the message to its internal storage and that the message will be delivered to a consumer at least once.¹  There is no further feedback to the producer.

A consumer can "snooze" a message for later retry by simply not deleting it (see `setSessionAcknowledgeMode` docs) or by actively resetting the [visibility timeout](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html) on the message instead of deleting it, which triggers SQS to leave the message in the *in flight* status until the timer expires, at which point it will again deliver the message for the consumer to retry.

Note, too, that a single SQS queue can have multiple producers and/or multiple consumers, as long as all the producers ask for and consumers provide identical services, but there is no intrinsic concept of *which* consumer or *which* producer.  There is no consumer-to-producer backwards communication channel, and no mechanism for a producer to inquire about the status of an earlier message -- the design assumption is that once SQS has received a message, it *will* be delivered,² so no such mechanism should be needed.

---

¹*at least once.* Unless the queue is a FIFO queue, SQS will typically deliver the message exactly once, but there is not an absolute guarantee that the message will not be delivered more than once.  Because SQS is a massive, distributed system that stores redundant copies of messages, it is possible [in some edge case conditions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/standard-queues.html#standard-queues-at-least-once-delivery) for messages to be delivered more than once.  FIFO queues avoid this possibility by leveraging stronger internal consistency guarantees, at a cost of reduced throughput of 300 TPS.

²*it will be delivered* assuming of course that you actually have a consumer running.  SQS does not block the producer, and will allow you to enqueue an unbounded number of messages waiting for a consumer to arrive.  It accepts messages from producers regardless of whether there are currently any consumers listening.  The messages are held until consumed or until the [`MessageRetentionPeriod`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-message-lifecycle.html) (default 4 days, max 14 days) timer expires for each message, whichever comes first.

Comment: Michael, thank you for your response. I forgot to mention, it is FIFO queue. I'm looking for a way to "snooze" or to reset the visibility timeout. Do you have any idea how to accomplish this taking into account my settings?

Comment: @CodeBusta that changes the dynamics.  [*"When you receive a message with a message group ID, no more messages for the same message group ID are returned unless you delete the message or it becomes visible."*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues.html)  In order to defer processing of one message in a FIFO queue, you have to be using different message group IDs, otherwise SQS will insist on processing everything in order and the consumer will not receive any more messages.

Comment: Michael, all I need is to FAIL the received message explicitly in the consumer without throwing Exception. Do you have any code samples?

Comment: The problem with that is we need to define what it avtually means to "fail" a message in the consumer.

Comment: Fail means the consumer will not acknowledge the received message even though it got the message. As far as I know, the FIFO queue will keep resending the same message until consumer acknowledges it. That's my aim. Right now I am accomplishing this by throwing an exception on the RED LIGHT and by processing the message on the GREEN LIGHT. And the queue is resending the message untill the green light on in my consumer. Note, the green and red lights are some business logic. All I need to know is whether it is possible to accomplish the same thing without throwing exception.